# Pacman error when trying to download a package

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am using BlackArch Linux. When trying to download a package I get this error:

```
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/core.db: Unrecognized archive format
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/extra.db: Unrecognized archive format
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/community.db: Unrecognized archive format
error: could not open file /var/lib/pacman/sync/multilib.db: Unrecognized archive format
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `for file in core extra community multilib; do file /var/lib/pacman/sync/$file.db; done`.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by a bad domain in the mirror list.

1. Remove existing sync files

   ```
   sudo rm -R /var/lib/pacman/sync/
   ```
2. Edit your mirror list and move your country mirror to the top of the list (You can use any text editor)

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
   ```
3. Now simply do

   ```
   sudo pacman -Syu
   ```

Comment: There's `yy` btw.

Comment: Both of them will work